# Fail to execute query on cassandra cli using bash script variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

Trying to execute the query through variable in bash script for cassandra command line but its getting failed.

**Script:**

```
[ec2-user@ip-192-2-2-7 tmp]$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash
IP=192.2.2.7
EQ='SELECT id,name,title FROM student where id=100'
echo $IP
echo $EQ
xyz=`echo \"$EQ\"`
echo "======"
echo $xyz
/usr/bin/cqlsh $IP -e $xyz
[ec2-user@ip-192-2-2-7 tmp]$
```

***Execution***

```
[ec2-user@ip-192-2-2-7 tmp]$ sh a.sh
192.2.2.7
SELECT id,name,title FROM student where id=100
======
"SELECT id,name,title FROM student where id=100"
Usage: cqlsh.py [options] [host [port]]

cqlsh.py: error: 'filename,' is not a valid port number.
[ec2-user@ip-192-2-2-7 tmp]$
```

Can someone suggest why unable to call the variable while executing /usr/bin/cqlsh $IP -e $xyz

If i run below command manually, It's working fine but not through variable in script.

/usr/bin/cqlsh 192.2.2.7 -e "SELECT id,name,title FROM student where id=100"

Comment: Please paste your script in https://www.shellcheck.net/ and make the corrections pointed.

Comment: Solved using echo $xyz | xargs cqlsh $IP -e